# How to sleep, wait or stop random number generator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, random, colors

**How to sleep, wait or stop  random number generator**

```
public void renderBackground(Canvas canvas) {
    //background
    Random rnd = new Random();
    canvas.drawARGB(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));     }
```

Comment: Please inform us with your problem/question ?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to sleep your execution, use the

`Thread.sleep(1000);`
comand, it will sleep the execution for 1 second.